# Angular 6 guard/canActivate only main route not secondary outlet

Tags: angular

I have a page with a main router outlet and a secondary/named outlet. The main router outlet has a route guard.

```
{ path: '', children:[
     { path: '', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [SomeGuard]},
     { path: '', component: SideNavComponent, outlet:'sidenav'}
]},
```

Here is the implementation of SomeGuard

```
import { of, Observable} from 'rxjs;
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class SomeGuard implements CanActivate {

  public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(true);
  }
}
```

If the guard returns true both outlets are routed properly however if the guard returns false none of the outlet are routed.

Comment: which Class did you use for inheriting SomeGuard?